# JXBrowser cannot close JFrame

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I am using JXBrowser 6.22.

```
Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        browser.loadURL("https://nf-test-jv.blogspot.com/");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
        browser.getDocument().findElement(By.cssSelector("#ReportAbuse1 > h3.title > a.report_abuse")).click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        frame.dispose();
```

When I execute the command click

```
browser.getDocument().findElement(By.cssSelector("#ReportAbuse1 > h3.title > a.report_abuse")).click();
```

The program will create a new frame pane
[image]

When I execute **frame.dispose();** it only closes the initial frame 1.Frame 2 doesn't close.
How can I close everything when I want. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `Frame.getFrames()` method. It gives a list of all the created frames by the application.

I would guess you could iterate through the Array to find the frame containing your Browser component and dispose() of that frame manually.

You would need to add a `WindowListener` to your main frame and handle the `windowClosing(...)` method to implement the above logic.

Comment: Your suggestion solved my problem, thanks a lot

A greed, but I still have a difficult problem with JXBrowser, I hope you can help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497451/how-switching-pane-frame-with-jxbrowser

Comment: Sorry, I've never used JXBroswer so I have no idea how it works.